# Как писать слово шт...рмовой?

Tags: орфография

Как написать слово шт...рмовой и объяснить, почему пишется так?

Comment: Чтобы посмотреть, как пишется слово, можете заглянуть в словарь.

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос не корректен.

Шт**у**рмовой (от "штурм") или шт**о**рмовой (от "шторм")?

Answer (score 1):

Если в шторм идут на штурм, значит, намерены в шт**о**рмовой (погодный) час шт**у**рмовым натиском сломить неприятеля.

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо соотносить написание, значение и структуру слова.